# if targetEnvironment(simulator) Code after 'return' will never be executed

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-simulator, compiler-warnings

I get the Xcode warning: "Code after 'return' will never be executed", when I use this:

```
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
    return
#endif

//Stuff that a simulator is unable to do
```

I use this in my code whenever a simulator truly can't do something, like scanning for NFC-codes. The easy solution would be to use an #else, but I don't like to put code within an #else only because Xcode doesn't realize the code **will** run when it's not a simulator. But perhaps a better argument, when I use the #else, all the code within the #else is greyed out by Xcode.

Is there a way to make Xcode realize that the code **can** be executed? Or suppress this warning somehow (without suppressing all warnings within this file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make Xcode realize that the code can be executed by using `#else`. As you say, it's the easy solution. It's also the correct solution.

You state:

> I don't like to put code within an #else only because Xcode doesn't realize the code will run when it's not a simulator.

This is not true. Xcode *does* realize. That's the whole point of what it is doing. Either the code above the `#else` or the code below the `#else` will be grayed out depending on your current build target. Select a real device and the `return` will be grayed out indicating that it won't be used. Select a simulator and the other code will be grayed out indicating that it won't be used.

In other words, Xcode grays out the code it knows will not currently be used based on the selected build target. You want this behavior so you know which code is currently active. It avoids any confusion about which code you are currently building and running.

---

Having said all of that, Xcode does provide a setting that allows you to disable this feature. Bring up Xcode Settings and go to the Text Editing tab. Enable or disable the "Dim inactive code" option depending on whether you want Xcode to gray out the relevant code or not.

Comment: You don't have to change the build target to see or edit the code. The grayed out code is still visible and editable. Though there's no code completion in the grayed out code which does make it harder to edit.

Comment: Definitely way harder to edit without completion, and also more annoying to look at compared to not-greyed out code

Comment: Ah, I found for the last part. Xcode has a 'Dim inactive code' option within Settings -> Text editing -> Display. If you turn this off, the code will be just as visible as any other code and code completion works again! :)